# Network Bridging on Linux for OpenVPN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, openvpn, bridge

I've been following all the OpenVPN Bridge tutorials I can, but I'm still missing something.  Does anyone know of a *super* detailed tutorial\explanation of bridging?

If anyone has bridging running, can I get a copy of your interfaces file to see how you've got it going.  (Obviously change the ip address, just please change them consistently.)

Answer (score 1):

I like Shorewall for firewalling, and they have a [detailed tutorial](http://www.shorewall.net/OPENVPN.html) on OpenVPN as well.

Comment: What are the prereqs to this tutorial? i.e. do I need shorewall and openvpn running on their own before this?

Comment: Yes Coyote, you need Shorewall running. I highly recommend it if you're writing iptables scripts or using some other kind of firewall configuration management, but I think the most helpful are it's tutorials, which help cover a lot of ground in relatively little time.

Answer (score -1):

I've actually got an OpenVPN bridge server running on DD-WRT.  I've posted the non-certificate bits of my client and server configs on pastebin here:  http://pastebin.com/vBpY7jWj

Comment: Paste them on here instead!  Pastebin entries expire after a while and hence this post is now next to useless :/

Comment: That link is dead now. And this is why we'd rather people copy content directly here than rely on outside links.